# Why button in navigationOptions => headerLeft that has onPress={action} does not work? React Native

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I am working in React Native and actually I am trying to implement a kind of custom side menu to avoid DrawerMenu implementation, I tried just to add an icon on headerLeft, but it does not work, it has no action when pressed.

```
class HomeScreen extends React.Component {
    static navigationOptions = {
        headerTitle: ('',
            <Image style={{ width: 150, height: 40 }}
                source={require('./images/logo.png')}
            />
        ),
        headerLeft: (
            <TouchableHighlight onPress={this._logout}>
                <Image style={{ width: 40, height: 40 }}
                    source={require('./images/hamburger_icon.png')}
                />
            </TouchableHighlight>
        ),
    }
}
```

The same when I try to place the button inside a mapView.

```
<View style={{ flex: 1 }}>

    <MapView
        ...
    >
        <Button onPress={this._logout} title="Logout" />
    </MapView>

</View >
```

But the same button, implemented inside a view works pretty well.

```
<View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
     <Button onPress={this._logout} title="Logout" />
    <MapView
        ...
    >
        ...
    </MapView>

</View >
```

I saw a solution using some components as DidMount, but I am not sure how to implement it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're trying to access the `this._logout` in a static method. Unfortunately as you have discovered that won't work.

It is possible to pass a function to the header. You can read more about passing functions to your header component [here](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/header-buttons.html)

It is fairly straight forward to do.

1. In your componentDidMount `setParams` with your logout function
2. In your `headerLeft` use the `getParam` property to access your function.
3. Notice how we are accessing the navigation props in the `navigationOptions`

Here is an example:

```
class HomeScreen extends React.Component {

  static navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => {
    return {
      headerTitle: ('',
      <Image style={{ width: 150, height: 40 }}
        source={require('./images/logo.png')}
      />
      ),
      headerLeft: (
        <TouchableHighlight onPress={navigation.getParam('logout')}>
          <Image style={{ width: 40, height: 40 }}
            source={require('./images/hamburger_icon.png')}
          />
        </TouchableHighlight>
      )
    };
  };

  _logout = () => {
    alert('logout');
  }

  componentDidMount () {
    this.props.navigation.setParams({ logout: this._logout });
  }

  render() {
    ...
  }
}
```

Comment: I am still having the same problem, the button has no action. I realized I have another componentDidMount that I use to watch the position of the device in the map. Do I have to write the line you gave and the all the stuff for the map in only one componentDidMount?

Comment: Yeah you should only have one componentDidMount

Comment: Thank you, your answer was really helpful

Answer (score 0):

As additional help to the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55030961/3175960)

If you use **this.** within the onPress event, you can use:

```
 this.props.navigation.setParams({ logout: this._logout.bind(this) });
```